# Change snackbar text in another Thread

Tags: java, android, android-snackbar, snackbar

After displaying a Snackbar, I run a Thread to execute actions. I want to change text according current progress in this Thread.

I create the Snackbar:

```java
private View snackbarview;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton upload = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.upload);
    upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Confirm ?", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .setAction("YES", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            lauchMyThread();
                            Snackbar snackbarconfirm = Snackbar.make(view, "Working...", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
                            snackbarconfirm.show();
                            snackbarview = snackbarconfirm.getView();
                        }
                    }).show();
        }
    });
}
```

I try to update its text in run() method of Runnable() :

```java
 public void run() {

            TextView tv = (TextView) snackbarview.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);

            try {

                tv.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        TextView tv = (TextView) snackbarview.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                        tv.setText("Task 1 performed.");
                    }
                });

                // and so on...
            }
 }
```

This method works for Textview, but crashes with Snackbar :

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

How to fix it?

Comment: Move `lauchMyThread();` line after `snackbarview = snackbarconfirm.getView();` line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start thread after `snackbarview` initialization.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you try creating a new snackbar inside run() function..

Comment: I could have indeed, I just prefer to reuse the existing one. I don't know what is more efficient.